# How do I delete a button after pressing it using tkinter in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game using Tkinter, and I'm trying to remove the buttons.

The code I'm using is:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

def ct():
    textA.destroy()
    tAb.destroy()

window = Tk()
textA = Text(window, width = 15, height = 1)
textA.insert(END, 'Choose a type.')
textA.config(state="disabled")
tAb = Button(window,  text = 'filler', command = ct)
```

I don't want to change it to much too.

Comment: What is this code doing that is different from what you expect? Is it throwing an error? Destroying the wrong thing? Destroying it at the wrong time? Something else?

Comment: First your code did not call any layout function, e.g. `grid()` or `pack()` on the `Text` and `Button` widgets, so they won't show up.  Second your code did not call `window.mainloop()`.  Your code destroyed the `Text` and `Button` widgets together inside `ct()` function.  If you just want to remove the button, just call `tAb.destroy()`.